# I want the program to keep running until the user enters 0 then the program terminates

Tags: assembly, emu8086

This is the code, I'm trying to make a simple program to check whether the number entered by the user is even or odd but how can make it keep running till the user enters 0?

```
org 100h
.data
msg1 db "Enter number : $ "
oddnum db 10,13,"Number Is odd! $"
evennum db 10,13,"Number is even! $"
num db 2
.code
mov dx,offset msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
div num
cmp ah,0
je even
mov dx,offset evennum
jmp print
even:
mov dx, offset oddnum
print:
mov ah,9
int 21h
ret
```

Comment: Before `sub al,30h`, put something like `cmp al,'0'`/`je exit` (where `exit` is some label). Also, using `div` to check for evenness is inefficient; a simple `test al,1`/`jz even` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still terminates once the comparison is done using "cmp al,'0' / je exit" , what I want is after the comparison is done the window's kept opened till the user clicks 0

Comment: Then add a jump to whereever it is you want to go after the odd/even mesage has been printed.

Comment: Never use `div` to divide by 2.  Computers use binary, you can just check the low bit to see if a number is even or odd.  You don't even have to convert from ASCII first, just `test al, 1` / `jnz odd` and fall through to even, or vice versa.